# Linear function gradient descent

Tags: python, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement a gradient descent algorithm for a simple linear function:

```
y(x) = x
```

Where initial hypothesis function is:

```
h(x) = 0.5 * x
```

and learning rate:

```
alpha = 0.1
```

[image]

Target function graph is blue and hypothesis is green.

Cost function:

```
J = 1/2m * sum[(h(x) - y(x)) * (h(x) - y(x))]
```

Gradient descent:

```
q = q - alpha/m * sum[(h(x) - y(x)) * x]
```

My implementation does not converge:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def y(x):
    return x

def get_h(q):
    """ Create hypothesis function
    
        Args:
            q - coefficient to multiply x with
            
        Returns:
            h(x) - hypothesis function
    """
    return lambda x: q*x 

def j(x, y, h):
    """Calculte a single value of a cost function 
    
        Args:
            x - target function argument values
            y - target function
            h - hypothesis function
            
        Returns:
            Value of a cost function for the given hypothesis function
    """
    m = len(x)
    return (1/(2*m)) * np.sum( np.power( (y(x) -h(x)),2 ) )

def df(h, y, xs):
    """Calculate gradient of a cost function
    
        Args:
            h - hypothesis function
            y - target function
            xs - x values
            
        Returns:
            differential of a cost function for a hypothesis with given q
            
    """
    df = np.sum((h(xs)-y(xs))*xs) / len(xs)
    return df

xs = np.array(range(100))
ys = y(xs)
hs = h(xs)

costs = []
qs = []
q = 0.5
alpha = 0.1
h = get_h(0.5) # initial hypothesis function
iters = 10
for i in range(iters):
    cost = j(xs,y,h)
    costs.append(cost)
    qs.append(q)
    print("q: {} --- cost: {}".format(q,cost))
    df_cost = df(h, y, xs)
    q = q - alpha * df_cost  # update coefficient
    h = get_h(q) # new hypothesis
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I account for q0 even if my target function intercept is zero?

**Update**

Answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/484750/linear-function-gradient-descent

Comment: Cross posting can get one in trouble.  Be careful.

Answer (score 1):

As you and @gunes pointed out in [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/484750/linear-function-gradient-descent), your formula are correct, but hyperparameters $\alpha$ and $iterations$ were not well adjusted.

Comment: Can you show a before/after plot or error track showing convergence?

Comment: I have added code, plot and output. Hope it helps.

Comment: Please see question update (answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/484750/linear-function-gradient-descent)

Comment: oh yep, you're right, my mistake